# Mongodb connect object with optional method

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise

I would like to create mongodb object that will have an optional method to create Collection after connect.

I've got something like this (mongo.js):

```
import url from 'url';
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

const getDbName = mongourl => {
  const mongoPathName = url.parse(mongourl).pathname;
  return mongoPathName.substring(mongoPathName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
}

export let db = null;

(async function() {

  const dbURL = process.env.MONGO_URL;
  const dbName = getDbName(dbURL);

  const client = new MongoClient(dbURL, { useNewUrlParser: true });

  try {

    await client.connect();
    db = client.db(dbName);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

})();
```

and if i would like to connect to db I'm just do this:

```
import { db } from './libs/mongo';
```

BUT my question is How to add optional method where i can create collection after connect to db?
I would like to get something like that:

```
import { db } from './libs/mongo';

db.then(() => { // if db is connected ->
 //createCollection or something else
})
```

I would like to do it with Promise, but I do not know how.
I would like to use this library at least in two places. In 1, connect with the base, in the second (separate) connect and create collections (setup)

Comment: An `import` should not by itself cause side effects (e.g. making the database connection).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tf3g67bc/3/ this is good?

Comment: you need `this.db = await this.client.connect()`

Comment: and `return await ...` is almost always incorrect

Comment: can you edit my question?

Comment: and in your outer code, you need `let db = await database.connect()` - also implying that your outer code itself needs to be an async function IIFE

Comment: no, that's not how it works here, sorry.

Comment: followed by `let users = await db.getUsers()`.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/isc-projects/perflab, especially `lib/database.js`.

Comment: Thank you. this is helpful. await of course need to be in an asynchronous function (which in this project is in the self-calling function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `import` should not by itself cause side effects.

Within the `mongo.js` module I would suggest exporting a class or object which contains an `async` method to return a database connection.

This is the method I've used in one of my own projects, where the constructor returns a new object that initially only has a `connect` method, which when invoked then attaches additional database-related functions to that object.

```
class Database {

    constructor(settings) {
        this.connect = async () => {
            let db = await MongoClient.connect(url, settings);

            this.someDbMethod = () => {
                return db.collection('foo').find(...);
            }

            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

with usage:

```
let db = await new Database(url, settings).connect();
let rec = await db.someDbMethod();
```

A constructor can't be async, hence why I use a secondary function to perform the actual connection.

Comment: i've got an error: "await is a reserved word" in usage

Comment: Are you making those calls to `await ...` from within a function tagged `async` ?

Comment: my editor show me error on "new" in
`import Database from './libs/mongo';
let db = await new Database().connect();`

Comment: Did you actually export that class?   Also, this is only supposed to be example code, not a fully working system.

Comment: yes of course :-) I know that this is just an example :-) I have made this example a bit more, but it does not work as it would

Comment: @JanuszO your jsfiddle code doesn't follow the pattern I've shown above, though.